# How to call function in C# from javascript at particular time

Tags: javascript, c#

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var startTime = new Date();
   var TimeTaken;
        //Start the clock!
   window.onbeforeunload = function ()        
   {
       var endTime = new Date();
       //Get the current time.
       var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);
       seconds = (timeSpent / 1000) % 60;
       TimeTaken = parseInt(seconds);
       //return TimeTaken;
       var temp = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID %>').value;
       temp = TimeTaken;
       alert(temp);
         <%PageO(); %>
  };
```

The above JS file runs when I close the tab/page in browser. But the function Which I called `<%PageO(); %>` executes when the programs starts running itself. This function call in code behind(C#) should execute only when the tab/page is closed not at the start of the program.

Any mistakes in this code?

Comment: use ajax jquery call see this links http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-call-C-Sharp-methodfunction-using-jquery-ajax/  and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/

Comment: thanks .. let me check ...

Comment: i already posted some links, are you using ASP.net web forms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This** - You have to use **[PageMethods](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var startTime = new Date();
   var TimeTaken;
        //Start the clock!
   window.onbeforeunload = function ()        
   {
       var endTime = new Date();
       //Get the current time.
       var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);
       seconds = (timeSpent / 1000) % 60;
       TimeTaken = parseInt(seconds);
       //return TimeTaken;
       var temp = document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID %>').value;
       temp = TimeTaken;
       alert(temp);
       // USE PAGEMETHODS FOR CODE BEHIND METHOD CALL
         PageMethods.PageO(function (response) {                 
        alert(response);
    });
  };
</script>
```

- **And you have to add `ScriptManager` in your .aspx page as below**

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">`

- **And in .aspx.cs file your Method with WebMethod as below**

  `

  `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`

  ```
  public static string PageO()
       {
          return "Yes this is working";
       }
  ```

  `

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN - Use PageMethod as above code example.

Comment: yeah thanks ... the function is called when I close the tab ... but I need to pass the temp value to C# function also ... so only I just moved the value to Label1.. But if i use public static ... I cannot access the controls ..

Comment: I would not recommend using asp.net ajax (formerly known as atlas) / webmethods, because these are outdated technologies, and while they are still supported it's a dead-end, especially given that better alternatives are readily available.

Comment: I'm not saying it didn't. I'm saying you are better off not using it, because it is not a good solution.

Comment: @zespri  -  the alternate option for PageMethod is `ajax call` - you can use `ajax call` also.

Comment: @SRIRAMRAMACHANDRAN  - if you want to pass `label` value to your static method. You can paas that value like  `PageMethods.PageO('label value')` and change your c# function like `public static string PageO(string value){}`